# inserting from a table to another table and activeting trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO SaleItem (ProdId, SaleQuantity)
SELECT ProdId, BasketProdQuantity FROM Basket;

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Stock_Decrease
    ON SaleItem
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ProdId INT
DECLARE @SaleQuantity INT
SELECT @ProdId=ProdId,@SaleQuantity=SaleQuantity FROM inserted
UPDATE Product SET ProdStockQuantity=ProdStockQuantity-@SaleQuantity WHERE ProdId=@ProdId
UPDATE Product SET ProdNoOfSold =ProdNoOfSold+@SaleQuantity WHERE ProdId=@ProdId
DELETE FROM Basket Where ProdId = @ProdId
```

When I insert datas from Basket to SaleItem it works well, but trigger only work for first id that inserted. How can I make it work for all ids?

EDIT!
I changed my trigger like this and it kinda worked I guess.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Stock_Decrease
    ON SaleItem
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Product SET ProdStockQuantity = ProdStockQuantity - (Select SaleQuantity From inserted Where Product.ProdId = inserted.ProdId ) Where Product.ProdId IN (Select ProdId From inserted)
UPDATE Product SET ProdNoOfSold =ProdNoOfSold + (Select SaleQuantity From inserted Where Product.ProdId = inserted.ProdId ) Where Product.ProdId IN (Select ProdId From inserted)
DELETE FROM Basket WHERE Basket.ProdId IN (Select ProdId From inserted)
END
```

Is that correct?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 if you asked that.

Comment: Correct, but overwhelmed with many `SELECT FROM inserted` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for each row or nested selects, just inner join with inserted :)

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Stock_Decrease
    ON SaleItem
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE P 
    SET ProdStockQuantity=ProdStockQuantity-i.SaleQuantity,
        ProdNoOfSold =ProdNoOfSold+i.SaleQuantity 
    FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON P.ProdId=i.ProdId


    DELETE B
    FROM Basket B
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.ProdId = B.ProdId
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always work with single-row triggers and that changed so many things for me. :)

Comment: Great, if it helps! Single-row is good if you guarantee that user will insert/update only one row (that is used in many places) but if you have many-rows inserted/updated the best way to use this data - is join it with what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

add **FOR EACH ROW**

```
DROP TRIGGER `TRG_Stock_Decrease`;
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Stock_Decrease
AFTER INSERT ON `TABLE` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ProdId INT;
  DECLARE @SaleQuantity INT;
  SELECT @ProdId=ProdId,@SaleQuantity=SaleQuantity FROM inserted;
  UPDATE Product SET ProdStockQuantity=ProdStockQuantity-@SaleQuantity WHERE ProdId=@ProdId;
  UPDATE Product SET ProdNoOfSold =ProdNoOfSold+@SaleQuantity WHERE ProdId=@ProdId;
  DELETE FROM Basket Where ProdId = @ProdId;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Question is tagged with `SQL Server` not `Mysql`